# Apache SSLCipherSuite That Avoids All DHE

Tags: apache-httpd

I am trying to set an SSLCipherSuite in my Apache that avoids ALL Diffie Hellman (due to application restrictions).

I have tried

`SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!DHE:!ADH:!ECDHE:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!SSLv2`

but that one gets an F in SSLabs.

Does anyone know of a suite that would get a better grade while avoiding DH?

Answer (score 0):

SSL Labs is clear about the reason for the rating, and you will only get a high score by using Diffie Hellman

TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

is the one exception I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm afraid so.
Do you know the translation of that into httpd.conf's SSLCipherSuite?